# Is this lightning-bolt-in-a-circle emblem from Captain Simian a reference to something?

Tags: cartoon, captain-simian

In the episode of "Captain Simian and the Space Monkeys" entitled "The Apes of Wrath," the heroes' ship's hologram generator is sabotaged.  Instead of creating the usual helpful (if short-lived) red-shirted holographic baboons, it produces an army of evil baboons led by a dictator with the speech mannerisms of William Shatner's James T. Kirk:

[image: evil baboon dictator]

The emblem of the baboon army, seen most clearly here on the leader's jacket, seems ever-so-faintly familiar to me, as if I'd seen it previously as the insignia of an evil organization in some other movie or TV show.  "Captain Simian" is rife with allusions to science fiction films and shows, so it seems quite possible, and there seems little other reason for the emblem's presence except as a reference.  I can't quite put my finger on it, though.

The emblem does superficially resemble that of DC's Flash, but I'm pretty sure that wasn't the intention, if it is a reference.

Comment: Are we talking beyond the obvious SS twin lighting bolts?

Comment: @Broklynite It's not so obvious to me, but I suppose it's a possibilty.  Seems like a pretty unlikely reference for a kids' show, though.

Comment: The lightning in circle motif is very common.  

In superheros you have Static Shock, the Flash etc.

It is also a common symbol of fascism, which is perhaps the general idea the cartoon was going for.  The most strikingly similar example is the Flash and Circle of the British Fascists.  My guess is they were going for a generic fascist dictator motic.